# Use service account instead of user account for pub sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-auth-library

I have deployed a service for the subscribing end of pub/sub following this [tutorial] (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub?hl=fr#run-clone-sample-repository-python).

After having some troubles with authentification, I can send messages via the Python client library on my local machine, using `gcloud auth application-default login` to authenticate myself.
My publisher code contains

```
credentials_path = (
    "path_to_application_default_credentials.json"
)
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = credentials_path
```

After reading several pages of documentation on authentification, I am still confused about this topic of using service accounts.
I want to integrate this code to an existing fastapi app deployed on CloudRun, for example publish a message via a http request.

What steps do I need to take to properly authenticate my app to publish messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ADC mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc) on Google Cloud. your `gcloud auth application-default login` is the right one to use it.

But you don't need to specify it in your code. The client libraries are designed to find automatically the default credential from the runtime environment.

You can have a try! Delete the 2 lines you mentioned on your publisher, it should work! If not, be sure that there is nothing defined in the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable on your local machine.

---

On Cloud Run, the mechanism will be the same: the libraries will detect your runtime service account (this one you can define when you deploy your cloud run, your [service identity](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity)).

you don't need extra code, and, above all, don't need a service account key file!

Comment: Thanks, it worked indeed. But if I may ask a followup, if the ADC mechanism authenticates our app based on the environment, a deployment on CloudRun in this case, then why in the subscribing [tutorial] (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub?hl=fr#integrating-pubsub) requires to create an account service? Since the endpoint is also deployed on CloudRun, we shouldn't need it ?

Comment: The service account is for PubSub, to authorize PubSub to invoke Cloud Run. It's not necessary the same as you have on Cloud Run. Or I didn't catch your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes more sense now